# Spark ml LogisticRegression failing for large libsvm format data

Tags: optimization, apache-spark, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am trying fit a Spark (1.6.0) ml.LogisticRegression for pure L1 regularization (elasticNetParam = 1.0, regParam = 0.1) model for a large ((2920874 rows, 2564827 features)) dataset that is saved in libsvm format. Since this is pure L1, an OWLQN optimizer is being called for the optimization part. However, in the resulting model, regression weights remain at their initial state and number of iterations seems to be just one, which means the optimizer exits after initialization for some reason. Moreover, the optimizer does not print any info messages which is another proof that it does not go beyond initialization step. My code is attached here:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineModel}
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.BinaryClassificationEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{ParamGridBuilder, CrossValidator}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import java.io._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
val training = sqlContext.read.format("libsvm").option("numFeatures", "2564828").load("/path/to/large/libsvm/training/data")
val test = sqlContext.read.format("libsvm").option("numFeatures", "2564828").load("/path/to/large/libsvm/test/data")
val lr = (new LogisticRegression()).setMaxIter(100).setElasticNetParam(1.0).setRegParam(0.1)
val lrm = lr.fit(training)
val output = lrm.transform(test)
val evaluator = (new BinaryClassificationEvaluator())
val metric = evaluator.evaluate(output)
```

Few relevant points:

1. This code was run from spark-shell (1.6.0) with 40 cores (10 executors with 4 cores each), 4gb driver memory and 4gb executor memory.
2. Same code with L2 regularization (elasticNetParam = 0.0) runs without any issues.
3. Same code (pure L1) with a smaller matrix format data used in the LogisticRegression test case runs without issues.